# Nested SQL Selects? DISTINCT from one column, and get the corresponding Mode for each value in another?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, aceoledb

So say I have this table called Key_Values that looks like

```
--keys--|--values--
  A     |    1     
  A     |    1     
  A     |    2     
  B     |    1     
  B     |    1     
  C     |    3   
  C     |    3     
  C     |    4
```

I need to write a single select statement that would get all of the distinct keys, and their respective values' mode. It would return this

```
--keys--|--values--
  A     |    1     
  B     |    1     
  C     |    3
```

I'm having some trouble figuring out the correct way to do this. I know I can do a DISTINCT(keys), but I'm not sure how to get the values from that.

Comment: please tag the dbms being used

Comment: Are you trying to get the lowest value for each key?

Comment: No, the mode - the value that occurs most frequently for that key.

Comment: what if there are two or more values tied as most common for a key?

Comment: I was just thinking about that. I suppose it should just return both tied

Comment: And what RDBMS are you using? An answer that works in SQL Server probably wouldn't be suitable for MySQL for example

Comment: It's actually all going to be done in Excel, so it's Microsoft Access / OLEDB

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions if your database supports it:

```
select key, value as mode
from (select key, value, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by key order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from keyvalue
      group by key, value
     ) kv
where seqnum = 1;
```

In MS Access, this is much more painful:

```
select key, value, count(*) as cnt
from keyvalue kv
group by key, value
having kv.value = (select top (1) kv2.value
                   from keyvalue kv2
                   where kv2.key = kv.key
                   group by kv2.value
                   order by count(*) desc
                  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll test it out and get back to you!